# PHP： INSERT INTO の行でエラーが出ていて解決できません

Tags: php

３４行目の INSERT INTO の部分でエラーメッセージがあるのですが、分かりません。
他の箇所がおかしいのかもです。

エラーメッセージ

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected variable "$sql" in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\chat2\index.php on line 34
```

ソースは

```
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>入力フォーム</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="">
名前 <input name="name" type="text">
出身 <input name="text" type="text">
<input type="submit" value="送信">
</form>

<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=chatlog;host=localhost';
$user = 'testuser';
$password = 'yasushi';

try {
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
echo "接続成功\n";
}


catch (PDOException $e) {
echo "接続失敗: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
exit();
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$log = $_POST['text']

// SQL作成
$sql = "INSERT INTO chatlog (id, name, log) VALUES (null, '$name', '$log')";

// SQL実行
$res = $dbh->query($sql);


$data = "SELECT * from chatlog";

$stmt = $dbh->query($data);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();


$stmt = $dbh->query($data);
$log_result = $stmt->fetchAll();



$i = 0;
while($i <30){
$i++;
echo('名前:');
print_r ($result[$i][1]);

echo('会話:');
print_r($log_result[$i][2]);
echo '<br>';
}



$dbh = null;


?>


</body>
</html>
```

３４行目は
`$sql = "INSERT INTO chatlog (id, name, log) VALUES (null, '$name', '$log')";` の部分です。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト? [PHP：　INSERT INTO の行でエラーが出ていて解決できません。](https://teratail.com/questions/313785)

Comment: 前の行に文終端のセミコロンが無いですね。

Answer (score 0):

OOPerさんが指摘されていますが、エラーが発生する行の２行上にある

```
g = $_POST['text']
```

を、

```
g = $_POST['text'];
```

にすれば解決すると思いますよ。
行末のセミコロンが無いのが原因ですから。

Comment: 初歩的なミスで、申し訳ないです・・・・
ありがとうございます。　感謝です。